# How to combine multiple VS Code themes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I come from Atom, where I had a way to define a UI theme, and a syntax theme.

Now with VS Code I'm using One Dark Pro theme, because I like how it styles the UI, but I would like to use a different syntax for the editors text.

Is there a way to combine multiple themes to obtain what I want?

Answer (score 1):

As of VSCode 1.13, you cannot do this without creating your own theme. We are tracking Atom-style support for separate syntax and UI themes here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25986

You can manually combine themes however. See [our built-in red theme](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/theme-red/themes) for an example of using different files for the syntax theme definition (`red.tmTheme`) and the UI theme (`Red-color-theme.json`).

Comment: It doesn't seem that this is the case for the linked red theme anymore. Instead, it seems to use `tokenColorCustomisation` to override the syntax colours one by one.